# school homework - grade calculation

Tags: c#

i have got questions.
my problem is The user is asked to enter 20 exam grades. If the grades entered are less than 0 or greater than 100, you should be asked to enter again. How can I do that?

```
        int not;
        bool test = true;
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        {
            Console.Write((i + 1) + (".Not:"));
            not = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            if (not < 0 || not > 100)
            {
                test = false;
                Console.Write("Try again!");
            }
            else
            {
                test = true;
            }
        }
```

I want to use bool while doing this. would be glad if you help. thank you in advance

i changed code but i used goto. I dont want use to goto. How can i use bool doing this ?

```
int not;
        int temp = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        {
            Console.Write("Add Not : ");

            backtoAdd:
            not = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            if (not < 0 || not > 100)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Try Again!");
                goto backtoAdd;
            }
            Console.WriteLine((i+1)+". Not : "+not);
            temp = temp + not;
        }
        Console.Write("sum of not : "+temp);
        Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: Could you share some code? Where did you stuck?

Comment: Please read [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) as well as [Open letter to students with homework problems](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems)

Comment: Also please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please learn how to create a [mre], and how to [edit] your questions to improve them.

Comment: This is called validation.

Comment: `&&` is logical AND. How can something be less than 0 and greater than 100 at the same time? You probably want `||` OR here (like you also phrased in your question)

Comment: You should repeat something until a condition is met. Or you can formulate this: `while` a condition is not met, you should keep on `do`ing the same thing. (Do you understand the hint? :-) )

Comment: no I did not understand. i am new to software. Can you show me how to change the code?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/statements/iteration-statements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned it can be done with a while loop and condition to stop the loop. You can simplify it, I have added comments in the code example:

```
// declarations
int counter = 0;
int maxExamGradesInputCount = 20;
int highestGrade = 100;
int lowestGrade = 0;

// as long as counter is not equal to maxExamGradesInputCount continue
while (counter != maxExamGradesInputCount)
{
    // we give input
    string? input = Console.ReadLine();
    // we try to parse our input
    var parsed = int.TryParse(input, out var grade);
    // if our input is parsed correctly
    if (parsed)
    {
        // we check if the input value between the given range
        if (grade < lowestGrade || grade > highestGrade)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Try Again!");
        }
        else
        {
            // if with in range count
            counter++;
        }
    }
}
```